# How to separate umongo's object document models from the main web app or how to avoid calling @instance.register where document models are defined?

Tags: python, mongodb, odm, umongo

While creating a web app using Flask or FastAPI, there would be a *main.py* file that basically instantiates and runs everything. I think that is also the right place for the database connections and initialization. So ideally I'd like to have a separate *model.py* file that basically just has the object document mapping definitions and nothing else.

Is it possible to do something like that in umongo?

I mean we need to call `@instance.register` above every object document map class. But if that is in a separate file and the DB is not initialized there, then in that file there are no instances. The instance would be declared in the *main.py* file.

For example, when you use Tortoise, it allows you to pass the whole *model.py* file as a module and register it with FastAPI like the following -

```py
register_tortoise(
    app,
    db_url=os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL"),
    modules={"models": ["models.model"]}, #model -> model.py which has all the class definitions
    generate_schemas=True
)
```

For demo, you can have the following as `model.py` file contents -

```py
from umongo import Document
from umongo.fields import StringField, URLField, DateTimeField
from datetime import datetime

class WebData(Document):
    url = URLField()
    summary = StringField()
    created_at = DateTimeField(missing=datetime.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.url
```

And the following main.py file that uses FastAPI -

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pymongo import MongoClient
from umongo import Instance

#db = MongoClient().test
#instance = Instance(db)

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/ping')
async def pong():
    return {'ping': 'pong'}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run("app.main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instantiate the instance at import but pass it a DB connection at app init.

common.py

```
from umongo.frameworks import PyMongoInstance


instance = PyMongoInstance()
```

model.py

```
from umongo import Document

from .common import instance


@instance.register
class MyDocument(Document)
```

**init**.py

```
from .common import .instance
import .model


def create_app():
    database = MongoClient().test
    instance.init(database)
    ...
```

(Note: in umongo 3 beta, `instance.init` is renamed to `instance.set_db`.)